# Checking if release date is newer than current date (Liquid/Html + Metafields)

Tags: html, date, if-statement, liquid

I am trying to make a simple check in liquid (the language on shopify) using a metafield (a value manually assigned to each item).

If you are unfamiliar with liquid you can check on the shopify forums as it is very easy o understand and very similar to most current languages, but I can use plain html or css in it as well if it'd be easier.

The metafield.global.release_date for the item in question has a string value of "17-10-2013". I can assign any value I choose as the release date, either in string or integer format. (I can for instance even embed a video).

What I want is to check the metafield.global.release_date of an item is newer or older then the current date, then simply change the output text to be either "item is available for Pre-Order", or "item is In Stock"based on the result.

The text output is simple and I can do it myself, the problem comes in reading the metafield release date as it is just plain text that is input by me for each individual item, I cannot figure out how to convert it to a format that can be used to check against the current date.

If I had more experience in css/html or had knowledge of java I may have been able to figure it out myself, but with my limited knowledge this is unfortunately something I cannot do yet.

Please can someone provide some simple code, such as an if-statement that I could use, if you need more information please just ask.

Thanks.

-EDIT-
Basically this is what I need the code to do:

-Check metafield.global.release_date

-Check Current Date

-If metafield.global.release_date > Current date THEN "Game is Available for Pre-Order"

-Else "Game is In Stock"

Comment: how is this related to CSS?

Comment: I was planning on adding the output text on the product page within it's own DIV, decided against it at the last second. It seems the css tag has been removed in any case.